# Cannot find MissingFeature to remove it from a Content Database

Tags: 2016

We are trying to clean up our Content Databases to remove errors such as `MissingFeature`. However we can't find these mission features using normal means, or any article I've yet found.

An example is

```
Category        : MissingFeature
Error           : True
UpgradeBlocking : False
Message         : Database [WSS_Content_DB1] has reference(s) to a missing feature: Id =
                  [2510d73f-7109-4ccc-8a1c-314894deeb3a].
Remedy          : Feature (Id = [2510d73f-7109-4ccc-8a1c-314894deeb3a]) is referenced in database [WSS_Content_DB1],
                  but isn't installed on the current farm. The missing feature might cause upgrade to fail. If
                  necessary, please install any solution that contains the feature and restart upgrade.
Locations       :
```

However the only place I can find a reference to this Feature Id is in the database itself under the `FeatureTracking` table.

I can directly delete these entries from that table and the errors go away.

Is there a supported method to remove these references to remove these errors from a `Test-SPContentDatabase` test?

**Things we've tried**

```
Get-SPFeature 2510d73f-7109-4ccc-8a1c-314894deeb3a
```

Returns nothing

---

Script from http://get-spscripts.com/2011/06/removing-features-from-content-database.html returns nothing

---

```
Get-SPFeature | ? { $_.Scope -eq $null }
```

Returns nothing

---

```
stsadm -o uninstallfeature -id 2510d73f-7109-4ccc-8a1c-314894deeb3a -force
```

Didn't fix this

---

```
select *
FROM [WSS_Content_DB1].[dbo].[Features]
where FeatureId = '2510d73f-7109-4ccc-8a1c-314894deeb3a'
```

Returns nothing

---

[Feature Admin](http://featureadmin.codeplex.com/) doesn't find anything missing

Comment: A similar question was asked here https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/228670/how-to-remove-sharepoint-feature-from-database.

Comment: You have already attached this DB to SPfarm or you want it attach?

Comment: It's already attached

Answer (score 0):

use this script it should help you. Remove ReportOnly switch after verifying it found what you need:

```
asnp Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell

function Remove-SPFeatureFromContentDB($ContentDb, $FeatureId, [switch]$ReportOnly)
{
    $db = Get-SPDatabase | where { $_.Name -eq $ContentDb }
    [bool]$report = $false
    if ($ReportOnly) { $report = $true }

    $db.Sites | ForEach-Object {

        Remove-SPFeature -obj $_ -objName "site collection" -featId $FeatureId -report $report

        $_ | Get-SPWeb -Limit all | ForEach-Object {

            Remove-SPFeature -obj $_ -objName "site" -featId $FeatureId -report $report
        }
    }
}

function Remove-SPFeature($obj, $objName, $featId, [bool]$report)
{
    $feature = $obj.Features[$featId]

    if ($feature -ne $null) {
        if ($report) {
            write-host "Feature found in" $objName ":" $obj.Url -foregroundcolor Red
        }
        else
        {
            try {
                $obj.Features.Remove($feature.DefinitionId, $true)
                write-host "Feature successfully removed from" $objName ":" $obj.Url -foregroundcolor Red
            }
            catch {
                write-host "There has been an error trying to remove the feature:" $_
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        #write-host "Feature ID specified does not exist in" $objName ":" $obj.Url
    }
}

Remove-SPFeatureFromContentDB -ContentDB "WSS_Content_DB1" -FeatureId "2510d73f-7109-4ccc-8a1c-314894deeb3a" -ReportOnly
```

*Hope it helps!*

Comment: Thank you for a reply, but unfortunately I've tried that. I will update a list of things I've tried.