# Feature 'f10fa067-3342-4d85-b5ac-92525d3491a7' for list template '10002' is not installed in this farm

Tags: 2016, migration, psconfig

I got an error while try to run PSConfig."Feature 'f10fa067-3342-4d85-b5ac-92525d3491a7' for list template '10002' is not installed in this farm"

I did not find this feature neither in FeatureAdminTool nor with PowerShell. Only I find this in AllList table in Content database.Even I did not find in Features Table in Content Database

[How to remove SharePoint Feature from Database](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/228670/how-to-remove-sharepoint-feature-from-database/230624#230624)

Anyone had faced this issue? Please help me to find solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

Issue :-

This error happens because a list or library was created in your SharePoint site based on a given list template that is no longer available.

A common scenario for this type of error is a list that was created with a template defined by a feature that has since been uninstalled. This makes the list invalid because the template no longer exists.

Solution :-

Re-install the feature in your SharePoint farm to make the list template available again .

created on a custom template.

I suggest you get list template feature ID via following PowerShell code:

$SPWeb = Get-SPWeb "http://SiteURL"

$SPList = $SPWeb.Lists['ListName']

write-host $SPList.TemplateFeatureId

Then access List Template Gallery (_catalogs/lt/Forms/AllItems.aspx) to check if this template exists or has been checked in.

Comment: Thanks @yash.kamdar,
Here the problem is, we did not find this feature solution code in our local repository. Please suggest me how to create a feature with the same feature GUID.